# Populate object type in SpringMVC using JacksonJson

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have Spring MVC application using Jackson to generate @ResponseBody as JSON.

I have following inheritance:

`@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "type")
public abstract class ParentClass`

`@JsonTypeName("foo")
public class Foo extends ParentClass`

`@JsonTypeName("bar")
public class Bar extends ParentClass`

Now If I return `List<ParentClass>` from controller directly it doesn't include type in it.

---

In the other hand if I have object like

`public class HigherClass {
    public List<ParentClass> parentClass;
}`

and return this from controller it generates JSON with proper `"type" : "foo"` or `"type" : "bar"` in it, which is exactly what I need also in case of `List<>`.

---

What I was able to find so far is http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-Serialization-list.jsp where he explains that what I need is to use `.writerWithType`  method in order to populate types.

Is there any way how to force spring populate JSON with type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bug found in either Spring or Jackson itself.
Issue on this was created on [spring Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12811) for more details